# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a dog adoption project. I have a function that receives two parameters: first is an array of numbers or a string, and the second one is a string. The function suppose to return an object the contains all the keys  that we will filter by to a dog service. The function in the dog service will return a new array of dogs containing the filtered dogs.

```
const filterBy = useRef<FilterBy>({ sex: [], ageRange: [], sizeAndWeight: [], breed: [], otherAnimalsInTheHousehold: [] })

const setFilterAnswer = (answer: string | number[], filterTopic: string) => {
        const filterSubjectsReplika = [...filterSubjects]
        const relevantSubject = filterSubjectsReplika.find(subject => subject.topic === filterTopic)!
        console.log(relevantSubject);
        const { filterTitle }: { filterTitle: FilterTopics } = relevantSubject
        if (typeof answer === 'string') {
            filterBy.current[filterTitle].push(answer)
        } else {
            filterBy.current[filterTitle] = answer
        }
        const filteredDogs=getFilteredDogs(filterBy.current)
setDogs(filteredDogs)

setFilter(filterBy.current)

    }
```

setFilter is a useState function that is transferd from the parent component.

I receive this error :

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

and this error :

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] & number[]'.
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

any help anyone?

- I've tried putting type guards
- I've tried changing the the filterBy type.